# angular filter on search and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app where I'm displaying a list of people. I have an input that I'm using to filter the list based on the string in the input.

Each person in the list also has an `status` string. I added a checkbox next to the string filter but I'm not sure how I can apply this to my filtering.

I'd like the string to filter on first/last name and the checkbox to filter on status

[Full Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/mLsbmfb7/8/)

the search filter is bound like this:

```
input type='text' ng-model='filterText'/>
<input type='checkbox'/> <!-- how do I get this to work -->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:filterText'>
            <span class=''>{{person.firstname}}</span>
            <span class=''>{{person.lastname}}</span> -
            <span class='color-oj'>{{person.status}}</span>

        </li>
    </ul>

$scope.people = [
        {firstname: 'abdul', lastname: 'ahmad', status: 'active'},
        {firstname: 'mahmud', lastname: 'samrai', status: 'active'},
        {firstname: 'gasser', lastname: 'badawi', status: 'inactive'},
        {firstname: 'ibtihaj', lastname: 'jasim', status: 'active'},
        {firstname: 'abudi', lastname: 'ahmad', status: 'inactive'},
        {firstname: 'ahmad', lastname: 'jasim', status: 'active'},
        {firstname: 'abdul', lastname: 'samrai', status: 'inactive'}
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is based on your fiddle, which is a little different than what you have posted here.

First, give you checkbox a model:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='active'/>
```

Second, change your filter slightly:

```
<li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:filterText | filter:{isActive:active} '>
```

Initially `active` is undefined so all people are displayed. Once you check the checkbox `active` will have a value and filter accordingly.

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLsbmfb7/9/)

Comment: thanks sorry I didn't see this sooner, was watching age of ultron :)

Comment: oh yea, and sorry about the different code, I had changed it but forgot to update the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one field you can use a strict search.

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='search.isActive'/>
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='search.anotherField'/>
```

you make an object with the field names matching the fields on the object your are filtering

```
<li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:filterText | filter:search:strict '>
```